# Sum and product of coprime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, coprime

Lets suppose we have $a$ and $b$ which are natural numbers and coprime.

Are $a+b$ and $a\cdot b$ then coprime to each other?

I can't find any information on that on the internet so I'd be thankful if anyone could answer my question.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you read the tag descriptions at all? This has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:division-algebras].

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Suppose $p$ is a prime dividing both $a+b$ and $ab$. Since $p$ divides $ab$, it divides [*fill the blanks*]. But then since $p$ divides $a+b$, it divides [*fill the blanks*].

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a + b$ and $ab$ are not coprime. Let $p$ be a prime such that $p \mid \gcd(a+b,ab)$. Since $p$ is prime, by [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$ (assume WLOG that $p \mid a$).

Now $p \mid (a + b)$, so we must have $p \mid (a + b) - a \Rightarrow p \mid b$. This means that $p \mid \gcd(a,b)$, contradicting that they're coprime.